# Can You Import an Excel File to a MySQL Database using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, mysql, import, import-from-excel

Can You Import an Excel File to a MySQL Database using phpMyAdmin? I am looking to buy this database that has the data of all Colleges and Universities in the US. The file is in Excel format. Can this be imported into phpMyAdmin?

Here is the site where I am going to buy the database from if this is possible: http://www.data-lists.com/universities-colleges-database.html?gclid=CPGXkN6H6aECFeQc5wodBFPRIg

You can download a sample of the database that has 10 entries. I have tried importing this into phpMyAdmin but this is the error I am getting:

> There is a chance that you may have
> found a bug in the SQL parser. Please
> examine your query closely, and check
> that the quotes are correct and not
> mis-matched. Other possible failure
> causes may be that you are uploading a
> file with binary outside of a quoted
> text area. You can also try your query
> on the MySQL command line interface.
> The MySQL server error output below,
> if there is any, may also help you in
> diagnosing the problem. If you still
> have problems or if the parser fails
> where the command line interface
> succeeds, please reduce your SQL query
> input to the single query that causes
> problems, and submit a bug report with
> the data chunk in the CUT section
> below:
> ----BEGIN CUT---- eNrtXAtsHMd5nt177R0FipQoiXqvICkiJd7xnnwJBnWiqFdIiubRjyQO5NVxSV51vGPuIYltVNNt
> CgS1azhSIre20sBNXLRp2jSOm9iIW8stYLcA3RZtmodjN3Zgp3FdtLWbokVg+/rPzO7evnkXyYna
> zhyHd/PvzP/N/PPP7Mw+vtGpqVNTQ+JITByJi2OjE0NiTIyLqYFkNBnKTMOR9lAoczuI95yYGRLL
> H8svSqWyXIrkc2cii/OLYiyWiiXEeDQ6EIa/+IAY6xuK9Q+lEh8W8/LCoLgnNL6UuXVsSExFopH+

And then at the bottom of the error it says:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near 'ÐÏà¡±á' at line 1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to import a binary file.

Try to export a sheet or a range of the excel file as a CSV file. This must be a reactangle with the same structure on every row.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the sample data and it looks pretty organized. Just save the excel file into csv (File -> save as). Then import it using PHPMyAdmin. I think it will work perfectly fine.

Good luck! :-)